# Mass conversion of thousand of excel files from xlsb to xls in sub-folders

Tags: excel, xls, xlsb

I have looked for an answer everywhere for this but couldn't find any so hopefully someone might be able to offer some assistance. I have a few thousand of excel files in a folder-subfolder structure and would like to convert them from xlsb to xls. I am currently using a vba macro to do this but it takes hours to complete the conversion. Is there any tool that can achieve this much faster? I'm not familiar with any other programming languages so please do provide as much detail as you can.

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you're currently using.

Comment: Hi Tim, I can post the code no problem but I'm preferably looking for a non vba approach. Some online tools convert 100s of xlsx files to xls and vice versa in only a few seconds using some sort of  batch conversion. I found this thread which is the opposite of what I am trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442698/convert-xls-to-xlsb-programatically  I don't quite understand however what I need to do

Comment: The thread you posted is about using .NET and Office Interop: that's just automating Excel the same way you're already doing, but using a different language to make the calls. There's nothing inherently faster about it.

Comment: I see, I found a few conversion tools online that convert i.e. from xlsx to xls, and converted as a test 2000 xlsx workbooks to xls in a matter of seconds. I was hoping for a similar solution.