# Convert file from xls to xlsb to reduce its size

Tags: java, python, sql

Is there any way to reduce the size of .xls file which was generated through an automated shell or tcl so that I can send it over mail automatically. As of now I am manually converting .xls file into .xlsb which reduce its size from 25 mb to 5 mb and then sending report daily to required person. So is there any esay way to do this?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442698/convert-xls-to-xlsb-programatically it may help.

Comment: And also google says http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-XLS/Features/Convert-XLSB.htm

Answer (score 1):

**Python implementation**

Convert xls file to csv:

```
import xlrd
w = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_filename, encoding_override="cp1251")
```

Convert generated csv to xlsb:

```
import win32com.client
excel=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
doc = excel.Workbooks.Open('csv_file')
doc.SaveAs( 'filename.xlsb', 50 )
```

Maybe you could directly convert from xls to xlsb instead of converting xls to an intermediate csv format.

Comment: Is there a way of converting xlsx to xlsb without converting to csv? This is because the formatting is getting lost when being converted to CSV format?